# Work around shinyapps.io "Disconnected from server"/"out of memory" issues

Tags: r, shiny

I'm a bit confused. I have a shiny app that displays rasters over a leaflet basemap. You select one of 9 rasters and it displays...simple. It works locally and takes 35 seconds to load. I've deployed it to shinyapps.io without any warnings. The bundle that I uploaded is ~8.5MB. When I run the app from their server it stops after 90 seconds and says "disconnected from server". Performace logs say "out of memory!". I doubt that the raster I'm loading is too large because it should allow up to 1GB with a free account. Based on a recommendation from here

[Disconnected from Server in shinyapps, but local's working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39116782/disconnected-from-server-in-shinyapps-but-locals-working)

I tried "Settings -> Advanced -> Startup Timeout" and set it to 300 seconds. Still the same problem. Is there something I'm missing?

R code

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(leaflet)
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
#setwd("E:/Projects/Shiny/ShinyCRP")


ui<-fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Population cores (top 25, 50, 75, 100) **App in development**"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(width=3, p("Select a bird please."),
                 selectInput(inputId="bird", 
                             label="Birds",
                             c("Baird's Sparrow"="./www/BAIS.tif",
                               "Bobolink"="./www/BOBO.tif",
                               "Chestnut-collared Longspur"="./www/CCLO.tif",
                               "Dickcissel"='"./www/DICK.tif"',
                               "Grasshopper Sparrow"="./www/GRSP.tif",
                               "Lark Bunting"="./www/LARB.tif",
                               "Ring-necked Pheasant"="./www/RNEP.tif",
                               "Sedge Wren"="./www/SEWR.tif",
                               "Sprague's Pipit"="./www/SPPI.tif"))),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Plot", p("The data presented in these maps are population cores of density
                           and distribution models." ),
                 leafletOutput("MapPlot1")),
        tabPanel("Summary", p("Working on this"),
                 fluidRow(
                   column(3, tableOutput(outputId="summary")),
                   column(3, tableOutput(outputId="summary1")),
                   column(6, plotOutput(outputId="summary2"))))
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$MapPlot1 <- renderLeaflet({
    bird<-raster(input$bird)
    pal <- colorNumeric(c("#022051", "#00ff8c", "#ffc700", "#ff3700"), values(bird),
                        na.color = "transparent")
    wmcrs <- "+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs"
    bird<-raster::projectRaster(
      bird, raster::projectExtent(bird, crs = sp::CRS(wmcrs)),
      method = "ngb")
    bird<-raster::as.factor(bird)
    leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$Esri.WorldImagery)%>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.TonerHybrid,
                       options = providerTileOptions(opacity = 0.7))%>%
      addRasterImage(bird, project=FALSE, colors = pal, opacity = 0.4);
      })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Performance log

```
2017-12-21T22:53:31.607046+00:00 shinyapps[251024]: Loading required package: sp
2017-12-21T22:53:32.431346+00:00 shinyapps[251024]: rgdal: version: 1.2-13, (SVN revision 686)
2017-12-21T22:53:32.431350+00:00 shinyapps[251024]:  Geospatial Data Abstraction Library extensions to R successfully loaded
2017-12-21T22:53:32.674556+00:00 shinyapps[251024]: 
2017-12-21T22:53:32.431352+00:00 shinyapps[251024]:  Loaded GDAL runtime: GDAL 2.1.0, released 2016/04/25
2017-12-21T22:53:32.431353+00:00 shinyapps[251024]:  Loaded PROJ.4 runtime: Rel. 4.8.0, 6 March 2012, [PJ_VERSION: 480]
2017-12-21T22:53:32.431352+00:00 shinyapps[251024]:  Path to GDAL shared files: /usr/share/gdal/2.1
2017-12-21T22:53:32.431354+00:00 shinyapps[251024]:  Path to PROJ.4 shared files: (autodetected)
2017-12-21T22:53:32.431355+00:00 shinyapps[251024]:  Linking to sp version: 1.2-5 
2017-12-21T22:53:32.674572+00:00 shinyapps[251024]: Listening on http://127.0.0.1:33580
2017-12-21T22:55:11.813279+00:00 shinyapps[system]: Out of memory!
```

Edit: Application metrics related to memory. Not sure what the units are in the second pic.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you set the instance size to 1GB in the application settings? Also, have you checked the memory usage on the local instance to know how much memory is being used on the local machine?

Comment: @LenGreski The instance size is set to 1GB. I'm not sure I fully understand how to get at local instance though. In shinyapp.io, if I got to metrics and look at figures: memory usage is~80MB; CPU usage for server is ~800 and local is ~100. I really appreciate your input. Thanks for taking the time to consider/respond.

Comment: From the docs. http://docs.rstudio.com/shinyapps.io/applications.html Please note that the memory metrics for the application may not reflect the consumption of all the available memory as the metrics are captured with one-minute granularity.