# immediate disconnect from Server in shinyapps, local working, no errors reported

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinyjs

After successfully deploying to shinyapps.io from Rstudio, the website initially loads, but then disconnects within 1-2 seconds.

- App:  https://ts404.shinyapps.io/TopicNetwork
- Repo: https://github.com/TS404/TopicNetwork

The app runs fine locally, and no calculations should be performed before the "calculate network" action button is clicked. I've checked similar questions here (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39116782/disconnected-from-server-in-shinyapps-but-locals-working)), however they don't seem applicable for such a small app. Is it anything to do with the github packages or D3? Any ideas?

Comment: Please, share your code

Comment: I don't know what's going wrong with your version, but I simply commented out about 20 `library` calls that were not necessary and it worked for me [on shinyapps.io](https://cjyetman.shinyapps.io/SO_test/).

Comment: Interesting that it's fixable with turning off the unused libraries. I'd left them in since I eventually intend to include their functions in additional tabs, so I'll have to do some testing on which are the ones that are causing the problem, it it's just a case of too many in total, or some combination.

Answer (score 0):

Based on CJ Yetman's observation, I deactivated all unused packaged and reintroduced them one at a time to test. That narrowed the problem down to [`chorddiag`](https://github.com/mattflor/chorddiag), which it turns out needs to be attached by `library()` in both `server.R` *and* `ui.R`, even if none of its functions are be used in the app.