# Shiny app is disconnecting after 20 seconds on iPhone but not on onePlus

Tags: shiny, shinyapps

I have made a shiny app that is deployed in shinyapps.io: https://hibashaban.shinyapps.io/muddakir/, I have noticed that the app disconnects from the server when I access it on my iphone (whether on chrome or safari) and leave the browser app for about 20 seconds. I have not been able to reproduce this problem in the chrome app on a onePlus phone so it seems to be an iOS or iPhone specific problem.

Is there anyway I can have it not disconnect from the server so quickly? Any ideas appreciated because I've run out of them. I have looked at timeout times on shinyapps.io/admin/#/applications/all but nothing seems to solve this specific problem.

I also tried deploying the app on an AWS instance using a shiny server. Same problem.

I've also tested this using another app I did not write and it did the same thing, so it's not a problem specific to my web app: https://jvadams.shinyapps.io/Testing/

[image]

this is what I got after 20 secs of leaving the chrome app..this is a problem because I know most of the users of my app will be using it on the phone, and lots of them have iPhones, I can't have them losing the progress just after a few seconds of leaving the browser app.

Comment: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/reconnecting.html, https://stackoverflow.com/a/40603002/9644150

this solved my issued.

Comment: my issue is not the initial deployment, it only disconnects if the person using it leaves the browser app for 20 seconds and comes back to it, all their progress is lost